# Everything freezes during booting virtual device in genymotion/android studio

Tags: linux, android-studio, genymotion

I can't understand what's going -  every time I try to boot virtual device in genymotion or android studio my laptop just freezes and needs to reboot. Every process just stuck. Can't fix this problem.

I boot my Linux from an external ssd.
Technical parameters of my computer is more over than enough to using android emulator like android studio or genymotion (`i7-10750H and 2070 RTX`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you create a regular VirtualBox virtual machine and boot it? If it also freezes then it is a pure VirtualBox problem and thus unrelated to Android.

Comment: I don't try any VM yet. I will try. 
I want try to check virtualization on my kali (it's not on VM) but don't know how.